# How to control vertical chapter position when using \setstrech?

Tags: spacing, positioning, koma-script, line-spacing, setspace

First time posting here, so apologies if I miss anything.

I'm using \setstrech to control the line spacing of my ToC, LoF, LoT, abbreviations, nomenclature, glossary, and reference sections. My thesis requires 1.5 line spacing; however, this means these sections are unnecessarily long.

However, this moves the vertical position of the chapter heading on the page (upwards) - so that it's in a different position compared to the rest of the document (at 1.5 line spacing).

MWE, displaying same issue with standard chapters:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \setstretch{0.5}
    \chapter{First Chapter Heading}
        \blindtext
    \endgroup

\chapter{Second Chapter Heading}
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `\setstretch` command *after* the chapter heading:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \chapter{First Chapter Heading}
    \setstretch{0.5}
        \blindtext

\endgroup

\chapter{Second Chapter Heading}
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to do so for the ToC, LoF etc. use `\AfterTOCHead` as shown in the KOMA-Script manual.

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\recalctypearea
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the `tocbasic` chapter of the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\AfterTOCHead`.